# http CONNECT request & ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, http, connect

Is there any way to make a connect request with ruby?

I don't see the verb supported.  Heres' the list from the docs:

```
  Net::HTTP::Get
  Net::HTTP::Head
  Net::HTTP::Post
  Net::HTTP::Put
  Net::HTTP::Proppatch
  Net::HTTP::Lock
  Net::HTTP::Unlock
  Net::HTTP::Options
  Net::HTTP::Propfind
  Net::HTTP::Delete
  Net::HTTP::Move
  Net::HTTP::Copy
  Net::HTTP::Mkcol
  Net::HTTP::Trace
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `open-uri` does the trick just fine.